# Tecla para evaluar expresion en Android Studio en Ubuntu

Tags: android, atajo

Se que en Windows en el debugger si yo uso la tecla `Alt + Click` encima del elemento que quiera evaluar me lo hace sin problema, pero, ¿sabéis si existe forma de cambiar este atajo? En Ubuntu funciona con `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Click` y como podréis imaginar no es nada cómodo en comparación con Windows, y además que ya estaba acostumbrado a este atajo, pero he tenido que pasar a Ubuntu, y me extraña que no se pueda cambiar dicha opción desde la configuración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ve a File->Settings->Keymap y filtra por evalu solo tienes que cambiar el atajo que te sea más fácil.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Rápido y sencillo, no lo había encontrado en las opciones, muchas gracias